# PL/SQL APEX_JSON how to parse to CLOB variable

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I'm trying to parse a json object like this one:

```
{
  "sites": [
    {
      "code": "code",
      "siteName": "site name",
      "country": "country",
      "arrayToClob": [
        {
          "field1": "field 1",
          "field2": "field 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to store the value of "arrayToClob" element into a Clob column of my DB and for that I'm trying to get the value of that element as a whole. This is what I tried:

```
APEX_JSON.parse(MY_JSON);
l_count := APEX_JSON.get_count('sites');
FOR i IN 1 .. l_count LOOP
    l_code := APEX_JSON.get_varchar2('sites[%d].code', i);
    l_siteName := APEX_JSON.get_varchar2('sites[%d].siteName', i);
    l_country := APEX_JSON.get_varchar2('sites[%d].country', i);
    l_value := APEX_JSON.get_array('sites[%d].arrayToClob', i);
 END LOOP;
```

where `l_value` is type `json_array_t`... but of course is not working. I've tried also with `varchar2` type and I've check other options here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29655

I don't know how to approach it, I don't know if it's even possible what I want... any tips will be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You mean that the value for "field1" is a CLOB value in your actual data ?  If that is *not* the case and it is just a varchar it's possible to use `JSON_TABLE` to get what you want in a plain SQL statement. Note that `APEX_JSON` isn't very performant.

```
with json_tab AS
(
SELECT
'{
  "sites": [
    {
      "code": "code",
      "siteName": "site name",
      "country": "country",
      "arrayToClob": [
        {
          "field1": "field 1",
          "field2": "field 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}' as data FROM DUAL
)
SELECT jt.code, jt.field1, jt.field2
  FROM json_tab t,
       JSON_TABLE(
       data,
       '$.sites[*]'
         columns (
           code VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.code',
           NESTED PATH '$.arrayToClob[*]'
             columns (
               field1 VARCHAR2(32000) PATH '$.field1',
               field2 VARCHAR2(32000) PATH '$.field2'
             )
         )
       ) jt;
```

`JSON_TABLE` does not support CLOB datatype as column - so if it really is a CLOB it won't work.

Comment: If the above resolved your issue then kindly accept it; if not then what is the remaining issue. This helps future questioners having the same issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.